# How can I investigate the differentiability of this function?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I leanred, if all partial derivatives exist and all are continuous, then it is differentiable. Am I wrong?

I tried same way for this problem, I think it is differentiable because

all the derivative exist and are continuous.

However, it is not differentiable at 0.

Why is it the case?

[image: The problem]

[image: Another problem]

// then I think... the functions of tho problems all have discontinuous partial derivative at (0,0)... right?

then, why is it differentiable or not?..

Comment: What a funny way to pose the problem. «Ah! This Looks Like A Case For Inspector Clouseau!»

Comment: (The «if $f(0,0)=0$» clause at the end is a little catastrophe of its own :-/ )

Comment: Sorry ... T_T I edited my question

Comment: I see you added problem "1" above. Are you sure the partials are discontinuous in this new problem? Did you check? I would guess that the higher degree found in the numerator is causing this function to behave better at the origin. We must investigate once again!

Comment: What do you mean by 'behave better at the origin'? I think both of two functions have discontinuous partial derivatives at the origin... since its numerator goes to zero.

Comment: But is the denominator going to zero as quickly as the numerator? (In the $(xy)^2$ case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partial derivatives evaluate to both to $0$. Thus, **if** the function is differentiable, it must be the case the differential is identically zero.

You're looking at $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left|\frac{f(x,y)-\nabla f(x,y)\cdot (x-y) }{\lVert (x,y)\rVert}\right|$$

This is  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left|\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|$$

What happens if you take the limit along $y=x$? Is it $0$, as it should be?

**ADD** The partial derivatives are $$\eqalign{
  & \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = \frac{{{y^2}}}{{{x^2} + {y^2}}}\frac{y}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} }}  \cr 
  & \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}} = \frac{{{x^2}}}{{{x^2} + {y^2}}}\frac{x}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} }} \cr} $$

Are you **sure** they are continuous at the origin?

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, it has different values for y=Mx depending on the constant M. But what's wrong with my solution? All partial derivatives are continuous.... but.. why?

Comment: @seongyun Are you **sure** the partial derivatives are continuous?

Comment: NO! The partial derivtives are most definitely NOT coninuous at $(0,0)$. Work them out carefully.

Comment: Oops!!!! I made mistake!! But, again I have confusing... I will edit my question

Comment: Finally, your 800th answer! Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

For the first one.
if $y = ax$,
$\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
=\dfrac{ax^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2x^2}}
=\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}
$,
so the function is not even continuous
at $(0, 0)$.

(This is, of course, not original.)

Comment: Marty, you seem to have missed an $x$ when simplifying, since the above should be $$\frac{ax}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$ The functions is continuous at the origin! Simply use the estimate $x\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$